# background-image doesn't work with transition

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a transition between two different background images with css.

It works to properties like background-color, but the transition between the images is abrupt and doesn't work with the transition atribute. As my elements are inside a css grid which cell's size can change in different devices, I can't just make another div inside and use the opacity for it because the sizes...

```css
    .logo_div{
        height: 100%;
    }
    .logo_grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .logo_box{
        background-image: url('...');
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        transition: background-image 1s ease;
        &:hover{
            background-image: none;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 300px; width: 300px;"> %This size can be different depending on the page
        <div class="logo_div logo_grid">
           <div class="logo_box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I expected a transition between the background image to none but it's abrupt.

Comment: what kind of transition do you expect?

Comment: you'll have to have 2 divs stacked to transition between the 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys for the help. Just in case you are in my situation and you can't (or may be don't know how to) work with opacities, I've got a solution:

I fixed it using the **background:** property with both color and url, instead of separated **background-color** for the color transition and **background-image** for the image one.

So now my transition is between two divs, one with the initial color and my image, and the second one between a second background color and a transparent png.

Thanks to everyone!

---

Answer (score 0):

Transition a property that is better suited for transition. Try `opacity`... hint: opacity value is `1` by default.

```css
.logo_box {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/200');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
.logo_box:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo_box"></div>
```

Comment: I couldn't do that because I had a background-color transition too, as some borders on the div that I didn't want to be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
 .logo_box:hover{
  background-image:none;
```

}